# Barcode in Center head [chead] and on every page

Tags: barcodes

> Hello everybody!

I am trying to get a Barcode in the Center head [chead] on every page like this work
[image]

First I decided to put the barcode inside a header. This worked but[image]
The code I had for the barcode:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%fancyhdr hiya li kadir khat asfal wa a3la waraka
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[right=2cm,left=2cm,top=1.6cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=morocco]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4,]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4,]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\khat[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4,]{ae_Cortoba}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{fancy}
%fancy tar9im wara9a 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\lhead{تاك}
\chead{ \begin{pspicture}(50mm,30mm)
        \psbarcode{978-3-86541-114}{includetext}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}}
\rhead{المستوى}
\lfoot{انتهى}
\cfoot{الصفحة
    $ 1 $
    من
    $ 1 $}
\rfoot{اقلب الصفحة}
\mathversion{bold}
\begin{document}
    \centerline{\textarabic{\khat وزارة التربية الوطنية والتعليم الأولي و الرياضة}}
    الثانوية الاعدادية الزهراء
    \hfill
    %hfill taktab mo9abil
    السنة الدراسية :
    $2022-2021$\\
    
    المستوى : ثانية علوم تجريبية
    \hfill
    المدة :
    $1$
    سا\\
    
    \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
    \centerline{الفرض الأول في مادة : الرياضيات}\\
    \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\\
    \underline{التمرين الأول :
        ($ 05 $
        نقط)}\\
    عين الكتابة العلمية للعدد :
    $ 0.01234567 $\\
    \begin{minipage}{10cm}
        ليكن الشكل المقابل هو التمثيل المبياني لدالة 
        $ f $
        معرفة بالعبارة :
        $ f(x)=x+1 $
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{6cm}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{tex}
    \end{minipage}\\
    \underline{التمرين الثاني}\\
    نص عربي\\
    $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } f(x) $
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Any ideas

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch thank you. can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using arabic language ...

Answer (score 1):

The barcode has a height of 30 mm. So in the geometry settings you must include a head height of at least of this size.

Also, the barcode needs to be moved for better centering.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%fancyhdr hiya li kadir khat asfal wa a3la waraka
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[right=2cm,left=2cm,top=1.6cm,bottom=2cm,
 headheight=90pt, includehead
 ]{geometry} %changed <<<<<<
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{fancy}
%fancy tar9im wara9a 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}

\chead{\begin{pspicture}(-8mm,-2mm)(42mm,28mm)% center/adjust position changed <<<<<<
        \psbarcode{978-3-86541-114}{includetext}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}}

\mathversion{bold}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum     
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you  for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to test your example, because it does not compile out of the box. I do not know how you compile it (`xelatex`? `lualatex`? How do you obtain the code?)

But one educated guess (but just a guess) is that you ignored this warning:

```
lilla.tex|| Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):  Make it at least 90.11264pt, for example:
\setlength{\headheight}{90.11264pt}. 
You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate: 
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-78.11264pt}.
```

So try to add, before `\begin{document}`, the suggested commands, and try again:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{90.11264pt}\addtolength{\topmargin}{-78.11264pt}
```

If that does not work, try to prepare an example that it's easy to test...

Comment: I compile with xelatex. ok thank you for your efforts. I will try to again